# How to calculate accumulation charge concentration (/cm3) as a function of dist. from the oxide-semiconductor interface in a MOS cap with n-type semi?

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors, charge, pmos

I am trying to calculate the accumulation charge concentration (/cm3) for the MOS capacitor with Au/TiO2/n-InSb, where n doped InSb is the substrate. So far the material I found focuses on p-type substrate and Inversion carrier concentration but hardly mentions anything about accumulation charge concentration. I am sure it's just a minor modification to the d(psi)/dx equation useful to calculate inversion carrier concentration but I am unable to find any solid evidence.

Any help is appreciated.